# Django ForeignKey on a View

Tags: database, django, view, foreign-keys

i'm building a django app from an existing database. for better or worse, i have a couple of views that i would like to base my models off. they look something like this:

```
class Device(Model):
  id = models.IntegerField( primary_key=True, db_column='node_id' )
  name = models.CharField(max_length=127, db_column='node' )
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'node' # db view
    managed = False

class Entity(Model):
  id = models.IntegerField( primary_key=True, db_column='_id' )
  device = models.ForeignKey(Device, db_column='node_id' )
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'entity' # db view
    managed = Fase
```

so things work okay. however, when i try to use a template that utilises the ForeignKey it is very slow:

```
{% for e in entities %}
  {{ e.device.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

looking at the logs, it appears to be repeating queries for each 'node_id', and ultimately timeout out.

(of course, if i do not include `e.device.name` is all quick)

is there a way i can optimise this?

to be fair, the 'entity' view already has the name of the device as another field (`node`), so i could use this instead but i would like the relation to exist.

Comment: try change **db_column='node_id'** to **db_column='id'**. I'm not sure, but the **node_** prefix might be inferred from the **db_table** meta option

Comment: the underlying entity view actually has the id reference to node as `node_id`; so putting in `id` actually fails with `"Unknown column 'entity.id' in 'field list'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try .select_related() in your view?

```
entities = Entity.objects.select_related('device').filter(...)
```

in the other hand, if it is and old database, and no autogenerated by django, probably node_id may not be an index in the database, this will slow down a lot any JOIN.

Comment: nice :) that seems to have worked! however, is there a way of doing this implicitly in the model definition? i feels kinda hackish to mix this with my views. cheers!